# Capture all possible path parameters jax-rs regex

Tags: java, regex, jax-rs

What is the regex to set for `@Path("<what_regex>")` to capture all possible path parameters depth (except for some specific path that is intended to be processed by other method)?

Like:

`/{path1}/{path1}/{path1}/{path1}/{path1}/` and so on

While still map these:

```
/create
/read
/update
/delete
```

To other Jax-rs resource methods.

```
@Singleton
@Path("/")
public class MyRest {
    @GET
    @Path({pathParam}) /* This works */
    public Response getSomething(...){}

    @POST
    @Path("create") /* Along with this */
    public Response createSomething(...){}

    // and so on
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First of all, you probably won't be able to catch these `/{path1}/{path1}/{path1}/{path1}/{path1}/` as you can't match an undefined number of parameters with only one regex.

That said, it seems the regex engine used is java's one (pretty logical). So you could use [negative lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure you're not catching your keywords. So I guess you could have something like that:

```
@Path("/{path: (?!create|read|update|delete).*}")
```

Then split the path var, using "/" as delimiters.

**Still**. Couldn't you just order your functions so the general case is checked last? I think it's the easiest...

Then you would just have to use:

```
@Path("/{path: .*}")
```

which is easier, and with less boilerplate.

**Edit:**
To be precise, the first one won't match URLs like "/create/anythingelse" as it simply forbids to have /create (and of course the same thing applies for your other keywords).

Comment: I tried checking this with http://xenon.stanford.edu/~xusch/regexp/ and I get Fail: Incomplete input

Comment: What exactly gave you this? [Try it](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=/%28%3F%21create%7Cread%7Cupdate%7Cdelete%29.*&env=env_java).

Comment: My bad, Jax-rs @Path mapping overrides mapping, i mean @Path("{path}") can co-exist in the same @Path("create")

Comment: I don't really see what the problem is. I'm hoping they can.

Comment: Anyway it seems you're forgetting a first mapping is done based of the method, so in your example, there couldn't be any conflict.

Comment: This worked: @Path("/{path: .*}"), what i mean was I really doesn't have to do this: @Path("/{path: (?!create|read|update|delete).*}")

Comment: Of course you don't, there's a first mapping based on the type of request, then you can use the order of your functions to do it too. The first solution would have been if a bear threatened you and you couldn't do otherwise.

Comment: Is this method of allowing all subpaths a security risk?